# Rewiring a three-season room addition over carport: junction boxes?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm cleaning up some poor workmanship from previous owners. We have a large three-season room addition on stilts over a carport. Wiring was run through the floor of the room/ceiling of the carport. We recently removed the loose plywood ceiling boards and heavily infested (and ineffective) fiberglass insulation, so now I can see the '70s DIY wiring job in all its glory. I would like to replace the ungrounded two-wire and put the junctions in boxes, but I'm not sure how feasible that is or what kind of hardware I need to use since the only access point for the junction boxes will be from below (i.e., outdoors but minimal exposure). Do I need waterproof boxes? Am I better off leaving well enough alone and letting this circuit get grandfathered in? The wire insulation looks in ok shape, but there are a number of small things I don't trust.

Comment: If you're saying there are cable splices buried in the fiberglass, that was never allowed under any electrical code.  No inspector would let that pass at any age.